# Two different jekyll output one for .html and another for .md

Tags: jekyll

Let's say we have a `post` the file lives in `_posts` and is titled `2013-05-11-stackoverflow.md`.

When you go to my site:

http://example.com/2013/05/11/stackoverflow.html

I would like to display the post with its normal `yml` `layout: whatever`.

But when you go to:

http://example.com/2013/05/11/stackoverflow.md

I would like it to display a special `layout: markdown` which would convert all the `yml` front matter into markdown via liquid template.

How can I make this happen?

I also have the challenge of making jekyll serve the file as plain/text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a better option would be to link to the source file at the bottom of the HTML page.

Example

[`raw.github.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.io/source/_posts/2012-03-20-spooked.md`](http://raw.github.com/svnpenn/svnpenn.github.io/source/_posts/2012-03-20-spooked.md)

Comment: I actually want to render out a non YML jekyll version with a special liquid layout where i take the post title and print it at the top like `# {{ post.title }}`.